# MySQL - Indexing of strings

Tags: php, mysql, string, performance, indexing

I'm looking for an optimal method for putting unique constraints on strings.

My use case is linking all email messages together by their "Message-ID" and "In-Reply-To" fields on the SMTP feed.

However, because the number of messages can grow into the millions, and we have no plans to delete anything, I need a way to index them very quickly.  The problem is that I'm under the impression that strings are inherently slower to index that numbers (If I'm wrong about that, please explain).

My solution so far is to convert the message ID to a `sha256` hash, then convert to into an 8 x 32 bit chunk 256 bit number like so:

```
// Its not actually written in C
struct message_id {
    int32_t id;
    char[255] originalMessageId;

    int32_t p01;
    int32_t p02;
    int32_t p03;
    int32_t p04;
    int32_t p05;
    int32_t p06;
    int32_t p07;
    int32_t p08;
}
```

And then put a unique constraint on all the nodes.

Now before anyone says anything about the quality of uniqueness of the message ID, I am aware, but this system isn't designed to have high integrity, just high performance.

So my question is this:

Will this suffice, or is there a trick to indexing strings in MySql that I've missed?

EDIT:  Adding Model Design.

MessageIdentity.php

```
/**
 * MessageIdentity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inbox_message_identity",
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={
 *              "p01", "p02", "p03", "p04",
 *              "p05", "p06", "p07", "p08"
 *          })
 *      })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Inbox\MessageIdentityRepository")
 */
class MessageIdentity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="originalMessageId", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $originalMessageId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p01", type="integer")
     */
    private $p01;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p02", type="integer")
     */
    private $p02;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p03", type="integer")
     */
    private $p03;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p04", type="integer")
     */
    private $p04;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p05", type="integer")
     */
    private $p05;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p06", type="integer")
     */
    private $p06;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p07", type="integer")
     */
    private $p07;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="p08", type="integer")
     */
    private $p08;

    /**
     * @param $string
     */
    public function __construct($string)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $bits = self::createBits($this->originalMessageId = $string);

        $this->p01 = $bits[0];
        $this->p02 = $bits[1];
        $this->p03 = $bits[2];
        $this->p04 = $bits[3];
        $this->p05 = $bits[4];
        $this->p06 = $bits[5];
        $this->p07 = $bits[6];
        $this->p08 = $bits[7];
    }

    public static function createBits($string)
    {
        $hash = hash('sha256', $string);
        $bits = array();


        // Bits are packed in pairs of 16 bit chunks before unpacking as signed 32 bit chunks
        // in order to guarrentee there is no overflow when converting the unsigned hex number into a
        // PHP integer on 32 bit machines.
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 0,  4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 4,  4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 8,  4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 12, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 16, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 20, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 24, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 28, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 32, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 36, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 40, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 44, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 48, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 52, 4)))));
        $bits[] = self::pluck(unpack('l', pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 56, 4))) . pack('s', hexdec(substr($hash, 60, 4)))));

        return $bits;
    }

    protected static function pluck($array)
    {
        return $array[1];
    }
}
```

MessageIdentityRepository.php

```
class MessageIdentityRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getExisting($string)
    {
        $bits = MessageIdentity::createBits($string);

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
        $qb
            ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p01', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[0])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p02', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[1])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p03', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[2])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p04', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[3])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p05', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[4])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p06', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[5])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p07', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[6])),
                $qb->expr()->eq('i.p08', $qb->expr()->literal($bits[7]))
            ))
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

MessageRepository.php

```
class MessageRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getLastWithMessageID(MessageIdentity $messageIdentity)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
        $qb
            ->where('m.messageIdentity = :identity')
            ->setParameter(':identity', $messageIdentity)
            ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;
        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

This is a model built using Doctrine2.  The message itself holds a foreign key to the `MessageIdentity` table.

The `MessageIdentity` is searched for by reconstructing the bit set, and searching on all of the columns which *should* perfectly utilize the unique constraint placed on the table.

The message is searched for based on the mapped identity, order by descending date, and only a single row is fetched.

Comment: So you have a table `messages` or something? Showing the structure could help answering your question.

Comment: you will eventually have collisions. you will note that any cryptography method has it's own moderate to extreme degradation of performance. Have you shown that using the smtp ID does not scale?

Comment: The problem of making strings unique in the database is usually solved the way you went with it - create a hash, store the hash, make it unique.

Comment: @Drew That is OK, because when matching a new message to another, I will only select the most recent match.  Its a usability tool.  To prevent accidental duplicates, I will use the message ID, plus a few other fields to "guess" whether it is actually unique.

Comment: @rlanvin The messages table has a "many-to-one" relationship with the "message id" table, (one to many because of the possibility of collisions mentioned by Drew).

Comment: @N.B. If that is the case, could you please link me some documentation confirming that?  Also, that would answer the question.

Comment: You should update your question with table structure and maybe an example of a query you would like to make, it would make it easier to understand the relationships and how the index is going to be used in the queries. Also, as @Drew pointed out, what are the scaling problems you are having now? How do you know the index won't scale?

Comment: @rlanvin I've added the model design to the question.  Sorry it is built in Doctrine2, but the annotation pretty much tell the story.  The reason I am unsure it will scale is because we have created indexes on email addresses in the past and it never scaled.

Comment: There's no documentation about unique string indexing. it's just common sense :) and your chosen solution is fine. We don't have much choice there actually. I usually hash something via `sha1` which is fine for most of my purposes and store the result in a 20-byte binary column.

Comment: @N.B. Ah, I though you were implying I was re-inventing something MySql already does natively.  It would make sense since I figure that is why there is a length limit on indexed varchars.

Comment: Sorry if I was misleading you - no, there's no native thingy whatsoever, I was just trying to confirm that what you did is ok. You can store the hash in the binary column using `UNHEX()` MySQL method so you can cut down on storage requirement (no need for varchars).

Comment: I don't think making Message-ID unique is good idea. You receive Message-IDs from different servers, structured in different ways, often envolving hashes that can have collisions. This means you may eventually get two different mails with the same Message-ID. In my opinion you should ignore this field and ID the messages yourself. Unless this is a client application that is handling messages stored in a specific server, like a IMAP/POP account, in this case you will need this field to make proper references.

Comment: @Havenard It doesn't need to be unique.  The hashing in this case is only performed to create a number of consistent size.  Which is then partitioned for indexing.  Ah, but the unique constraint is used to avoid duplicating rows unnecessarily.  If a duplicate ID is found, an existing one is reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are solving a non-existent problem.

Sure comparing two strings is a little slower than comparing two `INTs`.  But not enough slower to warrant standing on your head with MD5/SHA1/etc.  All the overhead of such would slow things down more than the string compares.

On the other hand, if you plan on having a unique string longer than 767 bytes, something needs to be done.  If so, I'll discuss some ways out.

Meanwhile, I will argue that SHA256 is gross overkill.  For a 128-bit MD5, "There is one chance in 9 trillion of a false duplicate in a table of 9 trillion strings."  For mere "millions", the odds are even more remote.

Another point...  `BINARY(20)` and `CHAR(20) COLLATE ..._bin` are handled identically.  More complex collations take *some* more effort.

**Addenda**

Background: Essentially the only index type in MySQL is BTree.  That is an ordered list.  It is also very efficient for a "point query" (given a key, find the record).  For InnoDB, the BTree blocks are 16KB blocks.  For a million rows, the BTree will be *about* 3 levels deep.  A trillion -- 6.

SHA256 / UUID / GUID / other digests -- all of these perform terribly when you have a very large number of rows.  This is because they are very random, and you are unlikely to have the desired block cached in RAM in the case of a very large table.

Here is a compromise solution, using an artificial table as my example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    in_reply_to VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET ...,
    ...
    KEY(in_reply_to(20))
    PRIMARY KEY (...)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT ... FROM foo
    WHERE in_reply_to = '...';
```

Notice that I do not have a sha256 or other digest.

`KEY(in_reply_to(20))` builds an index with the first 20 characters of that field.
`UNIQUE(in_reply_to(20))` would do likewise, but also constrain the 20 chars to be unique.  This is *not* what you want.

Here's how my `SELECT` works:

1. Look in that key, finding 1 or 2 or maybe several rows matching the first 20 chars.
2. Verify that the *entire* `in_reply_to` matches the search string -- *exactly*.
3. Deliver the resultset.

It would be good to pick the '20' to be a good compromise between

- Long enough to usually be unique
- Short enough to keep the key's BTree small.  (Smaller --> more cacheable --> faster).

You have probably noticed one thing missing -- MySQL is not doing the uniqueness check; your code will have to do that by performing some variant of my `SELECT`.

A SHA256 has 256 bits, so it needs `BINARY(32)`.  Even with 1e25 different documents, there is still a chance of about 1 in 1e25 of having a false duplicate.

Comment: The hashing algorithm isn't the part I'm worried about.  That part could take a whole second for the number of times it will get used.  As soon as the ID is collected and transformed, only the transformed version matters, I.E. the Sha256 encoded string with a fixed length of 64 chars.  The problem will occur when millions of these start being entered in.  Uniqueness is not very important in this scenario, it only needs to be very unlikely, so if reducing the hash complexity is better, so be it.  But search speed is what I really what to get O(1) times in.

Comment: This is why I've set up these partitions, in the hope MySql treats it like a tree lookup.  What I'm hoping to figure out with this question, is if MySql performs this kind of partitioning on indexed strings or binary values anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is quite informative.  The fortunate thing for me is that I can implement multiple ways of doing this at once and find out in a few months which is best.  I will add this example to my implementation.  Just to clarify, I need to lose the unique index, add the raw data to a `varchar[500]` and index with length 20?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, implement multiple approaches.  While doing it, see if you can figure out why one works better for _your_ situation.  Write a blog about it all.  Yes, lose the `UNIQUE` index, have `VARCHAR(something)`, and use the prefix of 20 (or some value).

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(foo, 15)), COUNT(DISTINCT( LEFT(foo, 20), ...` will give you some feel for how big a prefix to use.